# How to apply if statement to a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of 4 vectors

`Z` has no element inside it.

```
 liste<-list(A=c(1),B=c(1,2),C=c(1:3),Z=character(0))

lapply(liste, length)

$A
[1] 1

$B
[1] 2

$C
[1] 3

$Z
[1] 0
```

I would like to recreate a list with only vectors that have a non-zero length.

```
   $A
[1] 1

$B
[1] 1 2

$C
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `Filter` approach by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66555378/12158757) is the most elegant so far. Here is another one but with `subset` + `lengths`

```
> subset(liste, !!lengths(liste))
$A
[1] 1

$B
[1] 1 2

$C
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Filter` wrapped along with `lapply`.

```
lapply(Filter(length, liste), length)
```

The `length` returns 0 for the `character(0)` and it is changed to logical i.e. FALSE and all values greater than 0 as TRUE to `Filter` those elements, then get the `length`

---

A more efficient and vectorized option is `lengths`

```
liste[lengths(liste) > 0]
```

EDIT: based on @Waldi comments

Comment: for the second solution, I suppose you mean `liste[lengths(liste)>0]`

Comment: @Waldi i thought it would be better to have it in a `vector`.  Thanks